# How can i detect the ip, lan port & system details

Tags: c#, asp.net, network-programming

I need to make an application such that in a local area network, it's possible to get info about the LAN port, system details like RAM, processor, etc., and also the IP of the system in the LAN. Is it possible using asp.net?

Comment: On from the user or the site?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation), see also [LINQ to WMI](http://www.google.am/search?rlz=1C1SKPC_enAM383AM387&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Codeplex%20LINQ%20to%20WMI)

Comment: But this is server-side only which the OP doesn't want (as he specified in a comment after your reaction).

Answer (score 0):

Ip & port is possible if your server is placed in the lan, otherwise not without help
The port you already know as you defined it (port 80 by default).

IP: `Request.UserHostAddress()`

The rest you will need a 3'rd party application to tell you ie. a browser plugin